# Interface vs Class - visibilidade de métodos

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface

Eu fiz um trabalho para a escola e está a funcionar na perfeição.

No código tenho alguns métodos privados. Preciso de criar uma Interface dessa class para esconder esses métodos privados ou podem ficar na mesma class dos métodos públicos?

Neste momento tenho todos os métodos (públicos e privados) na mesma classe, mas o meu colega de grupo está a insistir que tem que criar uma Interface para esconder os métodos privados.

Comment: Seu colega está viajando. Seus métodos privados já estão... privados.

Comment: Ele insite que é preciso. Para esconder os métodos privados da class Main

Comment: Depende de quem você quer esconder, se você quer esconder da própria classe você precisa colocá-los em outra classe, mas não em uma interface pois elas não possuem implementação. Poste um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que possamos entender o que está acontecendo. Além do mais, não é possível criar um método privado em uma interface.

Comment: O trabalho funciona como deve ser e já fiz uma submissão e passou. Agora estamos só a tentar melhora-lo. O meu colega é que insiste numa Interface para os metodos privados

Comment: Amigo, se o método é privado nenhuma outra classe consegue invocá-lo (por meios "normais"). Não tem porque deixá-lo "mais escondido". Que argumento ele está usando como justificativa?

Comment: Está a dizer que "as Interfaces servem para esconder os métodos privados da main. Que são regras de Programação Orientada a Objectos."

Comment: @msm.oliveira Seguinte, se seu método `main` está na própria classe, ou se sua classe é **interna** à classe que contém a `main`, então nada vai impedir a `main` de acessar seus membros privados. Caso contrário, não é preciso fazer nada. Interfaces servem para desacoplar a "especificação" (contrato) da "implementação", não tem nada a ver com esconder membros privados (pois como disse o Math, se são privados, são privados, e ponto).

Comment: Tenho a classe Main que é a que vai interagir com o utilizador, neste caso, a consola. E tenho a classe Zombies onde está o algoritmo e as contas necessárias para o programa correr como deve ser. O programa está feito e a funcionar a 100%, o meu colega diz é que se deve por a interface por causa dos metodos privados

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces nada mais são que classes puramente abstratas. Ou seja, classes que não possuem membros definidos (i.e. não impõem nenhum detalhe de implementação), e todos os seus métodos são públicos e abstratos (i.e. estabelecem um contrato que a classe implementadora deve oferecer ao código consumidor). Por essa razão, uma referência a uma interface não tem acesso a nenhum membro privado da classe concreta.

Entretanto, essa é uma condição *suficiente* para esconder os membros privados, mas não **necessária** - é perfeitamente possível se obter encapsulamento sem user interfaces. O encapsulamento por `private` somente não se aplica à própria classe (obviamente, pois a classe precisa ter acesso aos seus próprio campos!) e - no caso de uma classe ser interna à outra (*inner class*) - à classe "de fora".

Aqui está um exemplo do que está e do que não está encapsulado em várias situações:

```
class Main {
    private int podeAcessar;

    interface IInterna { }

    abstract class InternaAbstrata {
        private int podeAcessar2;
    }

    class Interna extends InternaAbstrata implements IInterna {
        private int podeAcessar3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main a;            // pode acessar os campos privados

        Interna b;         // pode acessar os campos privados
        InternaAbstrata c; // pode acessar os campos privados
        IInterna d;        // NÃO pode acessar os campos privados

        Externa e;         // NÃO pode acessar os campos privados
        ExternaAbstrata f; // NÃO pode acessar os campos privados
        IExterna g;        // NÃO pode acessar os campos privados
    }
}

interface IExterna { }

abstract class ExternaAbstrata {
    private int naoPodeAcessar;
}

class Externa extends ExternaAbstrata implements IExterna {
    private int naoPodeAcessar2;
}
```

Como pode ver no exemplo acima, essa afirmação que "... tem que criar uma Interface para esconder os metodos privados" está incorreta, pois tanto no caso de `Externa` quanto de `ExternaAbstrata` o encapsulamento ocorre mesmo sem o uso de interfaces.